# Git for windows is not installing

Tags: windows, git

I'm trying to install Git for Windows from the following site https://git-scm.com/download/win. I've downloaded the 64-bit version and tried to install it on my Windows 8.1 laptop, but it gets to the following screen and never completes. Has this ever happened to anyone? I'm not sure what to do.  I've uninstalled and tried reinstalling multiple times.  I always get this screen.

[image]

Comment: Be sure to install is as administrator elevated for one just in case that's the issue rule that out with ah right-click run as administrator if applicable with the installation file after it downloads.

Comment: Unfortunately that wasn't it.  Same result :(

Comment: See if there are any release note known bugs, defects, etc, with the version you've downloaded. Maybe try to install an older version and disabling AV, etc. Check event viewer app and system log for relevant and more verbose error detail which may be related. Try one of these instead from [here](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and be sure to have x64 vs x86 for your system. These are quick ideas.

Comment: Please start the setup program like this: `Git-2.10.0-64-bit.exe /log=D:\mylog.txt`, substituting the log filename for a suitable one. Then, provide the log. If it’s too long, consider using a pastebin site or whatever.